# I have a Belgian travel document (Titre de voyage of 28/july/1951). What countries i can travel to without applying for a visa?

Tags: visas

I have a Belgian travel document (Titre de voyage of 28/july/1951). What countries i can travel to without applying for a visa ?
i would like to have the list if it's possible.

Thanks

Comment: I doubt such a list exists as such.

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95424/what-countries-can-i-enter-with-just-a-1951-convention-refugee-travel-document may be relevant

Comment: I suspect the list is only those countries in the Schengen area.